# Button style is different in firefox compared to Edge and Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, browser, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

My button seems to have white pixel gaps surrounding the button between the outer edges of the button and the button shadow in firefox. It also has a slower and much less smoother on hover animation compared to the animation in other browsers such as edge and chrome.

[Firefox button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n2Av.png)

[Microsoft Edge button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aINdh.png)

The class for the button is below

```
.button { 
margin-top: 0.5rem;
margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
border-radius: 9999px;
padding-left: 2rem;
padding-right: 2rem;
padding-top: 0.25rem;
padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.125rem;
--tw-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
--tw-shadow-colored: 0px 0px 0px 4px var(--tw-shadow-color);
box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow);
transition-property: box-shadow;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
transition-duration: 300ms;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```

Comment: Microsoft Edge Version 106.0.1370.37 (Official build) (64-bit)
Firefox Version 106.0.1370.37 (Official build) (64-bit)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue using the given code and have a totally different button style from yours in the pics. Would you please share the intact code that controls the style of the button?

Comment: @Jimmy similar to what kendrick-li already said, can you please update your example with all CSS HTML in a Code Snippet (hit `ctrl`+M while editing your question)